# get_results("select * from table_name where id IN($array)") but it assumes $array as "Array"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to pass an array from `get_results()` to another query call to `get_results()`

My code is like this:

```
$getids = get_results("Select ID from table_name");

$getData = get_results("Select name from table where ID In($getids)");
```

But when I run this code Instead of `$getids` it is taking `Array`

Comment: `$getids` in an Array. You need to pass all ids as a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$getids` is an array, if you try to echo it as a string, you will get the word `Array`. Instead, you need to [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it to get a comma separated list of values i.e.

```
$getData = get_results("Select name from table where ID In(" . implode(',', $getids) . ")");
```

But you can get the data you want directly by using a `JOIN` in your query:

```
$getData = get_results("SELECT name 
                        FROM `table` t1
                        JOIN table_name t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

$getids in an Array. You need to pass all ids as a comma-separated string like below:

```
$getids = get_results("Select ID from table_name");
$getids = implode( ',', $getids );
$getData = get_results("Select name from table where ID In($getids)");
```

Answer (score 0):

$getids is a php array, for use in string variables you must use "implode" function:

```
//first check array is not empty
if(count($getids))
{
  //if your array is same as: $getids=array("ID"=>[1,2,3,4]) you must first convert it to flat array same as :$getids=[1,2,3,4] 
  // for example: $getids=$getids["ID"];
  $sql="Select name from table where ID In(".implode(",",$getids).")";
}
```

Comment: Please check your code before posting. There is no function in PHP called `impload`